# Get a specific value from a proplist

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I have a proplist like this:

```
{ok,{todo,"todo-21","Foo2"}}
```

How can I get the without the "ok"?

I would like to output this as json in my controller:

```
{json, {todo,"todo-21","Foo2"}}
```

Is there some nifty way to do this?

Comment: Pedantic note: this isn't a proplist, because a proplist is necessarily a list.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, I would say:

```
tojson({ok,Todo}) -> {json, Todo}.
tojson({ok,{todo,"todo-21","Foo2"}}).
```

Comment: Or match out the `ok` when it is generated, for example `{ok,Todo} = ...`.

Comment: That was my initial suggestion also, but I considered somehow a bit more complicated (I don't know why though).

Comment: Question: Is the way I solved it possible, too? Or is that considered bad practice? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
element(2, {ok, {todo, "todo-21", "Foo2"}}).
```